# Android Custom Camera Pause feature

Tags: android, android-camera, mp4parser

How i can add pause feature in my custom camera as android media recorder class do not have pause method.Currently i am using mp4Parse library to merge video files to achieve pause feature but my video rotate after merge here is a code that i am using from mp4Parse android.

```
private class MergeVideos extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    //The working path where the video files are located
    private String workingPath; 
    //The file names to merge
    private ArrayList<String> videosToMerge;
    //Dialog to show to the user
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    private MergeVideos(String workingPath, ArrayList<String> videosToMerge) {
        this.workingPath = workingPath;
        this.videosToMerge = videosToMerge;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,
                "Merging videos", "Please wait...", true);
    };

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        int count = videosToMerge.size();
        try {
            Movie[] inMovies = new Movie[count];
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                //File file = new File(workingPath, videosToMerge.get(i));
                File file = new File( videosToMerge.get(i));
                //File file = new File(videosToMerge.get(i));

                if(file.exists()) {
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                    FileChannel fc = fis.getChannel();
                    inMovies[i] = MovieCreator.build(fc);
                    fis.close();
                    fc.close();
                }
            }
            List<Track> videoTracks = new LinkedList<Track>();
            List<Track> audioTracks = new LinkedList<Track>();

            for (Movie m : inMovies) {

                for (Track t : m.getTracks()) {
                    if (t.getHandler().equals("soun")) {
                        audioTracks.add(t);
                    }
                    if (t.getHandler().equals("vide")) {
                        videoTracks.add(t);
                    }
                    if (t.getHandler().equals("")) {

                    }
                }
            }

            Movie result = new Movie();

            if (audioTracks.size() > 0) {
                result.addTrack(new AppendTrack(audioTracks
                        .toArray(new Track[audioTracks.size()])));
            }
            if (videoTracks.size() > 0) {
                result.addTrack(new AppendTrack(videoTracks
                        .toArray(new Track[videoTracks.size()])));
            }
            IsoFile out = new DefaultMp4Builder()

            .build(result);

            //rotate video

            out.getMovieBox().getMovieHeaderBox().setMatrix(ROTATE_90);

            long timestamp=new Date().getTime();
            String timestampS="" + timestamp;

            File storagePath = new File(workingPath);             
            storagePath.mkdirs();  

            File myMovie = new File(storagePath, String.format("output-file-%s.mp4", timestampS)); 

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(myMovie);
            FileChannel fco = fos.getChannel();
            fco.position(0);
            out.getBox(fco);
            fco.close();
            fos.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        mFileName += "/output-file.mp4";
        return mFileName;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String value) {
        super.onPostExecute(value);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

What is best way to add pause feature in android custom camera ?

Answer (score 1):

Hi Zohaib I would like to give One Url as reference which may be satisfy your requirement as Follows:

https://github.com/sourab-sharma/TouchToRecord

Comment: My main problem is now video rotation.I am already merging videos  but video rotate after merging video chunks and this is same happening in your provided link but thanks link was good for touch and hold features.

Comment: Ok Zohaib i will try to work on Your Issue and gave you response as soon as possible If You like my answer then please support me to Vote up. Thanks In Advance.